# Use MSpec with MBUnit?

Tags: nunit, gallio, mspec

Does anyone know if it's possible to use MSpec with MBUnit instead of NUnit? Gallio seems to ignore all my tests when using MSpec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSpec is a BDD framework that does not rely on either NUnit or MbUnit.

Gallio (MbUnit's test runner) does not know about the MSpec tests because there is currently no integration between Gallio and MSpec in the MSpec master repository. [Scott MacLellan](http://github.com/smaclell) has created a [Gallio plug-in](http://github.com/smaclell/machine.specifications) in his repository that you can use until we merge it into the master repository.

Comment: As of yesterday, the Gallio plug-in is available via MSpec's master repository at http://github.com/machine/machine.specifications